# request sees absolute presigned url as relative

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to upload a file to Google Cloud Storage via a presigned URL. My URLs look like this:

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/<bucket-name>/2cd48340-8e52-430f-820a-03b33921af0a.zip?GoogleAccessId=storage-worker@<worker>.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1520810894&Signature=Dc0eMjOhfZnmBqUnwX8PsrAiAwhOybIQK8%2FC1QA9Df1m3vvxXQjlKB%2BC5GcQVdjwHkUSIZKp%2FJSeMZxBZkvMvbceEbzLEwbwZxKqpkG8NJP9yni%2B%2F5XH1Iqq%2BgVpfUpgcniuyEoG5RbDcLpgHh1C0EPf3wQrisPqV74uQ1tGdq5NrG2Zjqdw61zAc45O1HZ7MtOH6QaqX2MYrmK6RvdhB0yOKd28saBfZAGi47go8vcAb1CBjQT45WZePpPmV2O4DG%2FPYwnqyXvx%2BWHwKSPW9vGG4%2Fx4ZHIgFnh2di3joVEZNlmF2vK1Esmno%2FtS2YdheM9OfYFUbiApjRRqQGZIiA%3D%3D
```

My upload code looks like this:

```
const options = {
  method: 'PUT',
  url,
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/octet-stream',
  },
};

fs
  .createReadStream(newFilePath)
  .pipe(request(options))
  .then(body => {
    cb(body);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    cb(err);
  });
```

And I always get the following error:

```
(node:11300) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported
```

As far as I can tell, the URL is absolute - it starts with `https://` and everything! What could be going wrong here?

Comment: You're missing some requires from the code. What is `request` here? `request-promise`? It looks like you're mixing streams with promises.

Comment: Good question! I omitted it because I thought I had a `const request = require('request')` somewhere before it, turns out I had a completely different lib module being imported under the same name, which was causing the error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had a totally different module being imported as 'request' -

`const { request } = require('graphql-request');`

Switching to

`const request = require('request-promise');`

fixed the issue.